# scanning and saving input into an array. Then printing the input with certain stipulations

Tags: c++, arrays, scanf, error-code

What I am supposed to do is to scan 20 integers from the user, and save the integers into an array, then print the input. If an integer is repeated, print the first instance.

So, when I run the code in Cpp I get an error code, and I have no clue what the error means. The error code is "0x80070002" and "Unable to open file" with the description of file location. What do I miss?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 20;
    int input[SIZE];

    printf("Please enter up to 20 positive numbers.");

    //saveVar used for scan and saving into the array
    int saveVar;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", saveVar);
        input[i] = saveVar;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d, ", input[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (input[i] != input[j])
            {
                printf("%d, ", input[i]);
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using C arrays and I/O functions in C++?

Comment: You get the error when you try to run it or when you try to compile it?

Comment: Maybe unrelated: `scanf("%d", saveVar);` should be `scanf("%d", &saveVar);`. `saveVar` will be updated by `scanf` so you need to pass it by reference. If the compiler generates code that uses `saveVar` as the expected pointer rather than an `int`, bad things will happen. This is possibly flagged as a warning by your compiler. Do not ignore warnings. They usually mean your code is grammatically correct and compiles but does something you probably do not expect it to do. Justify or resolve all compiler warnings as you find them so you don't have to find them again the hard way later.

Comment: @Barmar when I run the program

Comment: @user4581301 okay thank you I will try it

Comment: You wouldn't have that problem if you used C++ I/O, e.g. `cin >> saveVar;`

Comment: Do you get the message asking you to enter numbers?

Comment: @user4581301 it works, thank you so much!

Comment: @Barmar I do it the regular way just because i don't understand the cin, cout way yet. and yes I did.

Comment: It's not the regular way, it's the unusual way in C++. It's only regular in C.

Comment: @Barmar oh okay. I didn't know, I'm not too familiar with cpp yet

Answer (score -1):

```
int main() 
{
    int i,j,k,n,a[20];
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements in the array:\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\nEnter elements of array:\n";


    for(i=0;i<n;++i) {
       cin>>a[i];
    }


    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        for(j=i+1;j<n;) 
        {
            if(a[i]==a[j])
            {
                for(k=j;k<n-1;++k)
                    a[k]=a[k+1];

                --n;
            }
            else
               ++j;
        }

    cout<<"\n";

    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";

    return 0;
 }
```

So basically, we ask the user for how many inputs they want to make in the array, a, and we use cin for that (because it is C++).

Your logic for removal of duplicate elements is incorrect. Have a look at mine, it is straightforward and a naive approach.

Please do have a look and let me know for any further doubts.